# ASP.NET Boilerplate template project build error

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-standard, aspnetboilerplate

We are getting build errors in the startup template project downloaded from https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates

**Downloaded startup template:** ASP.NET Core 2.x Multi Page Web Application.

**Errors:**

> 1. Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist
>      in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly
>      reference?) - MyCoreProject.Core - LoginManager.cs
> 2. Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Abp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) -
>      MyCoreProject.Core - LoginManager.cs
> 3. Error CS0308: The non-generic type 'PermissionChecker' cannot be used with type arguments - MyCoreProject.Core - PermissionChecker.cs
> 4. Error CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetAssembly' and no extension method 'GetAssembly' accepting a first
>      argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using
>      directive or an assembly reference?) - MyCoreProject.Core -
>      AppVersionHelper.cs
> 5. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore
>      2.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
> 6. Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.0.2 supports:
>      netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
> 7. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package
>      Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.2 supports: netstandard2.0
>      (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
> 8. One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.
> 9. One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
> 10. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.0.1 supports:
>       netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
> 11. Package Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.5.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package
>       Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 3.5.0 supports: netstandard2.0
>       (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

[image]
  [image]

Comment: Do you have EF Core 2 on your machine?

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version?

Comment: @R Sive, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an older version of Visual Studio, Following tools, are needed in order to use solution:

1. Visual Studio 2017 v15.3.5+
2. Visual Studio Extensions: Web Compiler and Typescript 2.0+
3. nodejs 6.9+ with npm 3.10+
4. gulp (must be installed globally)
5. yarn
6. SQL Server

Please Refer [PRE REQUIREMENTS](https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Development-Guide-Core#pre-requirements) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> ASP.NET Boilerplate template project build error

After created and downloaded your project, you still need to follow the below steps to run your application:

> - Open your solution in Visual Studio 2017 v15.3.5+ and build the solution.
> - Select the '**Web.Host**' project as the **startup** project.
> - Check the **connection string** in the **appsettings.json** file of the Web.Host - project, change it if you need to.
> - Open the **Package Manager Console** and run an **Update-Database** command to create your database (ensure that the Default project is selected
>     as **.EntityFrameworkCore** in the Package Manager Console window).
> - Run the application. It will show **swagger-ui** if it is successful.

Note:If you have problems with running the application, close and then re-open Visual Studio again. It sometimes fails on the first package restore.

There are also have some requirements you have to prepare before you run this app:

- nodejs 6.9+ with npm 3.10+
- Typescript 2.0+

Then restore the npm packages:

```
npm install
```

For some more details info, please check the [Documents for Startup Template Angular](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Angular#requirements).

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Install-Package EntityFramework
2) Add the below line in cs Projects
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
  </ItemGroup>
3) install netstandard from Nuget.
4)install this using package manager console 

Install-Package NETStandard.Library.NETFramework -Version 2.0.0-preview1-25305-02 -Pre
Install-Package NETStandard.Library.NETFramework -Version 2.0.0-preview2-25405-01 -Pre

5) Select the 'Web' project as the startup project.
6) Open the Package Manager Console, select the 'EntityFramework' project as the Default project and run EntityFramework's 'Update-Database' command. This will create the database. You can then change the connection string in the web.config.
7) Run the application. The default user name is 'admin' and the password is '123qwe'.
```